# Python beautifulsoup print by line #

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Okay so I'm currently using python beautifulsoup to output a specific line from a html file, since the html contains multiple of the same div class, it'll output every div containing the same class, example of this

CONTENT:

```
<div class=border>aaaa</a>
<div class=border>example</a>
<div class=border>runrunrun</a>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<div class=border>aaaa</a>
<div class=border>example</a>
<div class=border>runrunrun</a>
```

Now I only want #2 of div class border,

```
<div class=border>example</a>
```

now if i view source within chrome, it'll show content in number lines, so line 1 will contain

```
<div class=border>aaaa</a>
```

& line 2 will contain

```
<div class=border>example</a>
```

is it possible to output via numbered line using beautiful soup?

Comment: Use `soup.find_all('div', {'class':'border'})` and select the item you need.

Comment: That would have to be done manually.. I want it done automatically, plus there's 100s of the same element with the same name.. with 100 of the same requests.. i would have to do this 100s of times lol.

Comment: That's not what i mean. Eg: if you need the second 'div' use: `soup.find_all('div', {'class':'border'})[1]`

Comment: tried implementing this into my script but having issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629540/python-urllib2-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

find_all returns a list, so you can index it with `[1]` to get the second element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class=border>aaaa</a>
<div class=border>example</a>
<div class=border>runrunrun</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all(class_="border")[1]
```

returns

```
<div class="border">example</div>
```

Comment: I've tried implementing this into my script, but having issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629540/python-urllib2-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list with say 200 elements generated by soup.find_all... If the list is called div_list, you could just do an index loop (you want index 1,4,7 etc...)

```
count = 1
while True:
    try:
        print(div_list[count])
        count+=3
    except:
    # happens because of index error
        break
```

Or even shorter:

```
count = 1
while count<= len(div_list):
    print(div_list[count])
    count+=3
```