# Python urllib2 + Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

So I'm struggling to implement beautiful into my current python project, Okay so to keep this plain and simple I'll reduce the complexity of my current script.

Script without BeautifulSoup -

```
import urllib2

    def check(self, name, proxy):
        urllib2.install_opener(
            urllib2.build_opener(
                urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://%s' % proxy}),
                urllib2.HTTPHandler()
                )
            )

        req = urllib2.Request('http://example.com' ,"param=1")
        try:
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
        except:
            self.insert()
        try:
            if 'example text' in resp.read()
               print 'success'
```

now of course the indentation is wrong, this is just sketch up of what I have going on, as you can in simple terms I'm sending a post request to " example.com " & then if example.com contains " example text " in resp.read print success.

But what I actually want is to check

```
if ' example ' in resp.read()
```

then output 
       text inside td align from example.com request using

```
soup.find_all('td', {'align':'right'})[4]
```

Now the way I'm implementing beautifulsoup isn't working, example of this -

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

main_div = soup.find_all('td', {'align':'right'})[4]

    def check(self, name, proxy):
        urllib2.install_opener(
            urllib2.build_opener(
                urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://%s' % proxy}),
                urllib2.HTTPHandler()
                )
            )

        req = urllib2.Request('http://example.com' ,"param=1")
        try:
            resp = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
            web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(req), 'html.parser')
        except:
            self.insert()
        try:
            if 'example text' in resp.read()
               print 'success' + main_div
```

Now you see I added 4 new lines/adjustments

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'html.parser')

main_div = soup.find_all('td', {'align':'right'})[4]

aswell as " + main_div " on print
```

However it just doesn't seem to be working, I've had a few errors whilst adjusting some of which have said " Local variable referenced before assignment " & " unbound method find_all must be called with beautifulsoup instance as first argument "

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal example. Also try to indent your python code correctly.

Regarding your last code example, you should call `find_all` on `web_soup` variable: `web_soup.find_all('td', {'align':'right'})`.

Comment: I did state it was just a sketchup and indentations were wrong, but I just mainly want to know how to put this together regardless of indentations as I can fix that myself.. also I didn't understand what you meant, did you mean switch main_div = soup to main_div = web_soup?

Comment: If you want your questions to be answered, you should provide a minimal example such that other people can understand your problem. You provided 3 snippets, all of them are incomplete or with wrong indentations, such that it is very difficult to reconstruct your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your last code snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
main_div = soup.find_all('td', {'align':'right'})[4]
```

You should call `find_all` on the web_soup instance. Also be sure to define the `url` variable before you use it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "url to be opened"
web_soup = soup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'html.parser')
main_div = web_soup.find_all('td', {'align':'right'})[4]
```